# Soma acumulada últimos 30 dias SQL

Tags: sql, sum

estava precisando fazer uma consulta que me retornasse para cada data uma soma acumulada  dos valores dos últimos 30 dias, para cada loja, daquela data de referência.

```
SUM(receita) OVER (PARTITION BY loja order by data ) AS acumulado
```

utilizei essa parte do código para fazer uma soma acumulada e deu certo entretanto eu precisava que ele acumulasse só 30 dias e não sei como fazer.

Minha tabela é algo como:
| Dia | Loja | Receita |

Comment: Pesquise por datetime functions do Banco de dados em questão

Comment: Para Qual DBMS ?

Comment: Poderia incluir um exemplo dos dados da sua tabela, o resultado que você obteve e o resultado esperado?